# What functions need to be virtual in order to output specific items?

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

Im trying to output the following:

```
apple
banana
orange
banana
```

Do I have to make my functions virtual in order to output?

```
class Red
{
public:
    void PrintMe() { Foo(); Bar(); }
    void Foo() { printf("pear\n"); }
    void Bar() { printf("lemon\n"); }
};

class Green : public Red
{
public:
    void PrintMe() { Bar (); Foo(); }
    void Foo() { printf("apple\n"); }
    void Bar() { printf("banana\n"); }
};

class Blue : public Green
{
public:
    void Foo() { printf("orange\n"); }
    void Bar() { printf("grape\n"); }
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Green g;
    Blue b;

    Red *pR1 = &g;
    Red *pR2 = &b;
    pR1->PrintMe();
    pR2->PrintMe();
}
```

Comment: Voted to close this sick question.  Too many issues to be possible to answer.

Comment: No vote to close and disagree with the -1. This question has two correct answers (yes and other issues, or no because). Food for thought.

Comment: $20 says the OP never selects any answer and never fixes the question to make sense.

Comment: I'm not betting on the first proposition.

Comment: So clueless on what path I should take next with this. All my questions are related to a single project and this is the only thing holding me back. I totally realize that this way isnt the most proficient but its what I have to work with.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can get "apple banana orange banana" as the output with your current setup, because:

1. To print "apple banana" using `Red *pR1`, you have to make `Foo` and `Bar` virtual.
2. Once you declare a function as virtual, it stays so in all derived classes.
3. Now since `Bar` is virtual, `pR2->PrintMe()` will print "orange grape" -- there's no way it'll print "banana".

Comment: The OP could declare Bar const in Blue.  Then it wouldn't be an override.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: I only said it's not possible "with the current setup", because the OP's question was only about making "some functions virtual".

Comment: Well, current setup doesn't have any virtual functions either, so there you go ;)

Comment: I reached the same conclusion, +1. Maybe @Noah Roberts wants to upvote my more pedantically correct answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, otherwise you're printing two Reds.

Answer (score 0):

`Red::Foo()` and `Red::Bar()` need to be virtual.

Comment: `Green::PrintMe` calls `Foo` and `Bar` in reverse order compared to `Red::PrintMe`.

Comment: @larsmans Yes, but if I'm not mistaken he wants to print "apple banana" which means that he needs to call `Red::PrintMe()` and that `Green::PrintMe()` is a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problems with your code: you define a class named **red** , but then *Green* inherits from a class named **Red**

Anyway, if red is your base class and you want the other classes to override its methods, you need to declare them *virtual* indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: PrintMe() needs to be virtual.

Explanation:

Since you want to call the method of the specialized object pointed to by the base class pointer, you need to make that method virtual.

```
// Base class pointer pointing to specialized class
Red *pR1 = new Green();

// If PrintMe() is not virtual, this call will be Red::PrintMe(). 
// If you want to call Green::PrintMe, make it virtual.
pR1->PrintMe();
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL!  Nobody has gotten this one right!

You need to make PrintMe virtual because the order of foo/bar can change.

You need to make Foo and Bar virtual because they do different things.

You need to make the DESTRUCTOR virtual because you're implementing a polymorphic higherarchy.  This one isn't even in your code at all.  Your particular test `main()` doesn't need it, but most reasonable, non-trivial uses would.

Edit: OK, maybe I got it wrong too.  If you don't want PrintMe to actually override behavior when used through a base pointer then it should NOT be virtual.  Your code is kind of confusing.  Nobody would do it that way.